# The bidirectional binding requires "Path" or "XPath" exception. Windows WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, combobox, datagrid

In a Datagrid which looks like this I am getting an exception:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ModuleGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Module Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="uName" Binding="{Binding Path=UniqueName}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Features">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Feature.Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Features}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Feature}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

So far so good almost everything works fine. But, when i select on Item on my ComboBox :

[image]

I get the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Die bidirektionale Bindung
>   erfordert "Path" oder "XPath"."

The C# Code behind is an Object, which Contains a List of Features (`List<Feature>`), which contains `Feature`s. I initialize it like this:

```
 List<Module> test_3 = pPP_2.Components.Modules.Values.Cast<Module>().ToList();
 ModuleGrid.ItemsSource = test_3;
```

Edit: The Module Class:

```
class Module
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Property, double> Properties { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }

        private Dictionary<Material, double> content = new Dictionary<Material, double>();
        public Dictionary<Material, double> Content
        {
            get { return content; }
            set { content = value; }
        }
        public double FillingCapacity { get; set; }
        public double FillingAmount
        {
            get
            {
                double ret = 0;
                foreach (double a in Content.Values)
                {
                    ret += a;
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
```

The Feature Class:

```
class Feature
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FeatureType { get; set; }
        public Property UsedProperty { get; set; }
        public double MinValue { get; set; }
        public double MaxValue { get; set; }
        public double ChangePerMinutePerLiter { get; set; }
    }
```

Property Class:

```
    class Property
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is `Module` a custom class? If so, could you add that to your post? Also, is there any more information in the `StackTrace` for the exception such as line numbers, etc?

Comment: Added everything. There is no information about lines etc. in the `StackTrace`, it only tells me it failed while compiling `main()`

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Would you also be able to show how you are creating `pPP_2`? I think there may be an issue with WPF resolving the properties at some level for that object's values. Could be due to one of the values not being a property, but rather a plain old fields. Also, have you tried declaring `test_3` as a property with a getter and setter?

Comment: pPP_2 is the Folder where i store the project. I really dont know how i create it. I declared test_3 as a property, still doesn´t work..

Comment: Do you mean that `Components` is a class that exists in a Folder called `pPP_2`, and the namespace for items in that folder is `WPFProjectName.pPP_2`?  For example, it could look like 
`namespace WpfApp4.pPP_2
{
    public class Components
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Module> Modules { get; set; }
    }
}` I've got this working on my test project here, so I may not be doing something with the Dictionary `Components` the same way you are.

Comment: have to get some sleep tho. thanks for your help for now. back in about 10h

Comment: Not a solution yet, but here's something you could do to remove one of the potential problems. Replace `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` (and everything inside) with `DisplayMemeberPath="Name"`. This lets the ComboBox know to display the `Name` property of `Feature` without having to declare your own template. One less binding to worry about.

Comment: @IRezzet: You are trying to bind to a non-existing `Feature` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the features combobox it appears you are binding to an internal drop down of values on the `Modules` object and wanting to change that list to one item... where that one can be selected? This makes no sense.

---

To rectify the issue do these steps

1. First off you need a static (unchanging) list of features somewhere to bind to.
2. Remove `Features` from `Module` and replace it with an id property, right now to avoid confusion call it `FeatureName`.
3. Use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` which will allow for one value to be changed based on an id. To say again, sadly, the id on the `Feature` class is `Name`. For to be more realistic it should be an `Id` number field on `Feature` which could identify and associate that way; as mentioned in #2 we will call our id `FeatureName` for now to avoid confusion.

---

**Step 1** This step sets up a `public` property of  `List<string>` named `FeatureList` on your window's (or page, or control's)  datacontect (a VM?) where you will have loaded the *id values* from all features such as these strings: `{ "Heinzen", "Coolen", "Ein", "Klinen", "Yagermeisters", ... }` in again, that list of `String`s (not `Feature`s).

Then put that list on a page resources somewhere such as

```
<Window.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="FeatureList"
                          Source="{Binding FeatureList}" />

</Window.Resources>
```

**Step 2** Remove from `Module` `public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }` and replace it with `public string FeatureName { get; set; }`

**Step 3** Now you will replace the Frankenstein `DataGridTemplateColumn` where you had a combobox with a *more civilized* `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. Which will allow for the display *and editing/selecting* of the value which will choose/display the feature.

Put this in as such:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Feature"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding FeatureName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FeatureList}}"
                        Width="100" />
```

This should give you a good start on the issue and how to *properly* use a combobox.

Comment: I know you are a college student...but please tell me you got the `Die Toten Hosen` reference in the above code as a humorous side note. :-)  If not, I'm getting old.

Comment: just startet working so i did not have time to review your answer properly BUT i caught your drift with `Die Toten Hosen` tho. Not yet getting old ^^

I will try the solution and comment again!

Comment: okay so i can not remove the features list from Module because those are Parsed into the app when the programm starts. so i get Features and every Module gets a list of Features parsed, when the programm starts. I believe thats why the whole editing thing doesn´t work tho. Still cant handle it

Comment: Are the features unique to the module...or are they one list which is given to all modules? If all features are the same, then you can base the static list as mentioned off of the first module's feature list. But the selection drop down has to store (and at other times get it's) it's value from one location. That is what you have to work out.

Comment: Every Module gets its own Features, Like an Oven can Heat, or a Fridge can Cool and/or Freeze etc.

so i guess they are unique to the module

Comment: That is fine...what is the purpose of the drop down in itself? Where does the user selection of the drop down come into play? How are the value(s) being persisted? Or are they, what happens to the selection?

Comment: I want the user to be able to choose what Feature a Module should use in a specific simulation, like if he wants to freeze the water, he chooses the Freezing feature from the cooler.
And then pass it to some method that actually runs the application, but that is not coded yet.

Comment: So that selection has to be saved to a property on the `Module`. This is the crux of the situation. One can't save back to the list of features...With a combobox it is generally used to select one item. You will need to create a property which will hold that one user selection. That is what is missing. If you need to select multiple features, you may want to consider a list of checkboxes that the user selects.

Regardless the crux of your problem is **where** to save the user selection. If not selections. The drop down may not be what you ultimately need.

Comment: i see .. Okay i will try to make it happen.
Thank you very much for your help! i´ll comment again once i got it to work.

Comment: My post solves the problem, but it does not solve the design issue. GL

Comment: wait u find my project ugly:(((?

Comment: Ugly no...not seeing where that was said. The coding (design) needed changing to accommodate a result to produce what you want in the long run. :-)

Comment: i am just kidding^^ 
Thank you very much for helping!